# Scoring badminton and squash in Spanish

Tags: traducción, juegos

I play badminton and squash with a friend from Colombia.  Of course, she is fluent in Spanish but did not play these games in Colombia.  So, she is not certain of the terminology.  I am not looking for a very formal answer but what typical semi-serious players use.  Some specific points:

How to say zero in a score.  In English "love" is usual e.g. For 2-0 we say "two love".

How to say equal scores.  In English, we say 5-5 as "five all".  At the moment, we say "cinco iguales".

Some others: "my serve", "your serve", "game point", "tie", "let", "fault".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambos son juegos poseen cosas en común, abajo dejo unos enlaces para ampliar;

- Alto / Stop
- Fuera
- Mal / Mala / Bola Mala
- 0-0 / cero - iguales
- 2-0 / dos cero / dos a cero
- 5-5 / cinco iguales / cinco a cinco / empate /iguales
- saque /saco yo / sacas tu / tu sirves / tu recibes - (my serve", "your serve)
- repetición del punto / repite / vuelta - (let)
- sin repetición / sin vuelta (no let)
- punto / juego y set / set de desempate / set final / set 1 / set 2
- remate
- juego / juego completo
- stroke / punto / punto bueno (squash)
- Pie Fuera (Foot Fault) , (squash)
- Falta (Foul)
- Baja / Bola Baja (squash)

Para saber más;

---

**Squash**

https://www.squasheros.com/como-jugar-al-squash/diccionario-squash/

**Badminton**

https://badmintontotal.net/diccionario-badminton